# Multiple 'Echos' showing up above table

Tags: php, mysql, html

In my program I have created a table that is scrollable, everything is working fine as far as the scroll bar showing up,the proper data being returned and so on.

What is strange and I can't locate why, is that above the header of the table the word 'echo' is repeated 7 times, one for each record being returned.  I've obviously got some flaw in my code, but I haven't been able to locate it, any help is appreciated

```
    <?php
    echo "<div class='scrollableContainer'>";
    echo "<div style=' height: 125px; width: 535px; font-size: 10px; overflow: auto;'>";
    echo "<table class='referrals scrollable'>";
    echo "<thead><tr> 
            <th class='date'>Date</th>
            <th class='name'>Student Name</th>
            <th class='email'>Email</th>
            <th class='phone'>Phone</th>
            <th class='status'>Status</th>
    echo </tr></thead>";
            $query2 = "select * from students where referred_by ='$referral_id_to_use'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);
            if($num_rows>0){
                 while  ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                  {
                       extract($row);
                         $student_name=$first_name.' '.$last_name;      
                 if($current_status=1)
                     {
                        $student_status="Active";
                     }else{
                        $student_status="Inactive";
                     }
        echo "<tr>\n
              <td class='date'><div>$date_joined</div></td>
              <td class='name'><div>$student_name</div></td>
              <td class='email'><div>$emailaddress</div></td>
              <td class='phone'><div>$phone_number</div></td>   
              <td class='status'><div>$student_status</div></td>
        echo </tr>";
            }
        }       
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    ?>
```

Again the extra line of echo's appears above the table header.

Thank you

Comment: I think you have extra "echo"s before: echo </tr></thead>"; line 11.  and also here: echo </tr>". Remove it

Comment: Thanks to those who answered, and thanks for validator link, I had forgotten about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the word `echo` as data between a `</td>` and `</tr>`.

Since text isn't allowed there, the browser is error recovering and moving it to somewhere it is allowed (before the table).

```
<td class='status'><div>$student_status</div></td> echo </tr>";
```

Delete the word 'echo' from the source.

This type of thing is easier to pick up by examining the generated HTML, and running the generated HTML through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org), rather then just comparing the PHP to the rendering in the browser.

Comment: Thank you as soon as the system will let me i'll check the answer as accepted.

Comment: Check my answer too, you actually have it in 2 different lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
echo "<thead><tr> 
        <th class='date'>Date</th>
        <th class='name'>Student Name</th>
        <th class='email'>Email</th>
        <th class='phone'>Phone</th>
        <th class='status'>Status</th>
echo </tr></thead>";
```

The last row. Also in the body as can be seen in @Quentin's answer.

Comment: Vlak, Quentin hit it first, thanks for your input I appreciate it